Why didn't the Jews complain when they had to wait for Miriam 7 days in the Midbar when she had Tzara'as? They complained about everything else?
This whole parsha, B’nai Yisrael are constantly complaining. Pesach Sheni (Lama Nigora), Kohanim about missing the Nessi'im dedication, the mis'onenim, Moshe to Hashem about them, etc. Yet when the whole Jewish nation is told they will be waiting in a hot desert seven days for Miriam, nobody said a thing? Why?

Maybe that’s the whole point- despite them being such a rowdy bunch, they had the utmost respect for Miriam because of the role she played and therefore had no issue waiting for her

But even she spoke Lushen Hora. Clearly, they were all one inch away from losing it (on their level) and all of a sudden 3 million ppl have zero issue waiting 7 days in a desert?

Commentaries, and in a lot of Chassidus, emphasise that the Jews in the desert, despite the pshat, were on a very high level. On their level these things are considered "complaints", but it's hard to fathom because what they were complaining about is far above the type of petty things we complain about (e.g. complaining they missed a chance to give Hashem a present, or in other cases complaining that they don't have any zechus, so they don't deserve water and therefore will die). In light of that, maybe the question falls away. What's to complain about waiting, on their level?

Actually thats pretty good. The person that asked me this said that we all complain but when it comes to doing we always get it done.

they complained 10 times over 40 years, those complaints were along the lines of we dont have water and were gonna die. i complain more often than that about petty things by the time i get out of bed in the morning. pesach sheni wasnt a complaint but a good thing, same with aharon wanting to also serve hashem. its like saying a child is complaining by asking how can i help.

It appears that the stories of complaints and a story of Miriam's tzaraas ran in parallel. The Torah is concise.

If the question is solely based on the wording in Chumash, Abarbanel has a long discussion about the term מתאננים - complainers on Bamidbar 11:1. From his point of view, complaints resulted from people's bad character traits and from being accustomed to Egyptian practices. Based on etymology of the word מתאננים, he concludes that complaints were an expression of personal desires. People express their desires constantly. The reason these desires did not enter the story of Miriam, is perhaps, there was nothing new in the complaints during these 7 days. I.e. these are parallel stories.

I just thought of an answer based on another post on this site. The question is, why would they complain about lack of meat if they had livestock? Someone quoted the Rambam that they didn't have enough for everyone, and only the leaders ate meat daily.
Based on that, I would say Pessach Shainee, The lack of Meat, Even Ahron about not being part of the nessuim, some had, and some didn't so the ones that didn't have, complained. Its human nature.  By waiting for Miriam 100% of the people were in the same boat of discomfort, nobody had an advantage so they didn't mind waiting and nobody complained.

Why do you think only leaders ate meat?  Everybody ate mann. Parashat haMann also describes that everybody had meat from slav.

You asked:

Why didn't the Jews complain when they had to wait for Miriam 7 days in the Midbar when she had Tzara'as?

And then:

Yet when the whole Jewish nation is told they will be waiting in a hot desert seven days for Miriam, nobody said a thing? Why?

Well, the Torah tells us: וַתִּסָּגֵר מִרְיָם מִחוּץ לַמַּחֲנֶה שִׁבְעַת יָמִים וְהָעָם לֹא נָסַע עַד הֵאָסֵף מִרְיָם - Miriam was expelled from the camp for 7 days and the nation didn't travel until she was readmitted.
So, some thoughts:

Why do you think the people knew they were being stationary because of Miriam? Their itinerary was erratic and unpredictable. We don't actually have a record of how long they stayed in most locations.

Why do you think they were waiting in a hot desert? They were in a climate-controlled cloud-enclosed environment. Food was heavenly and water was in abundance. Why would they want to decamp and travel to another location - it's not like they were rushing to get anywhere. (Well, they were, but they had a 40-year deadline and they couldn't arrive early.)

Besides, the next location was also in the same "hot desert" - what do they gain by leaving 7 days earlier or later?


Finally, you added to the title:

They complained about everything else?

Well, you seem to have found proof that they didn't complain about everything. I think that's an unfair accusation against our nation. (Considering you're discussing the Parsha of Miriam being punished for speaking against Moshe, you may want to edit that out.)

It's a poor interpretation that Miriam spoke "against" Moshe. The precise wording indicates that she was defending Moshe. The midrash tells, that after many people in the camp became prophets, Tzipora stated that she felt for their wives, who would not have relations with their husbands. Hence Miriam said...

@YDJ - so Miriam was punished for defending Moshe? Or maybe you'll find a Medrash that this was a reward? Please explain. וּמַדּוּעַ לֹא יְרֵאתֶם לְדַבֵּר בְּעַבְדִּי בְמֹשֶׁה

I answered here with the sources. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/131451/what-was-miriams-lashon-hara
